# Draw Pyramid in Typescript using d3.js to use it in power bi

Tags: typescript, d3.js, powerbi

I want to  build a custom visual in Power BI(Pyramid) with help of Typescript and D3.js ,need help or links to document.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals

Comment: please consider following this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
so we can better answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-visuals/ - actual docs are here.

github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals - is outdated